# using PowerShell to send SMS message containing Greek characters

Tags: powershell, http-headers, http-post

I am using this code in PowerShell v7, to send an SMS message which contains Greek characters.

```
$message = "testing greek characters ΓΔΘΞΦΨΩ"
$senderId = "smsto1"
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $apikey")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
$body = "{`n`"message`": `"$message`",`n`"to`": `"+357$clientPhone`",`n`"sender_id`": `"$senderId`",`n`"encoding`": `"unicode`"`n}"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://api.sms.to/sms/send' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

The problem is that the message arrives with every Greek character shown as a question mark. Like this:

```
testing greek characters ???????
```

I tried changing the encoding option in the $body variable to UTF-8, ISO 8859-7 and unicode, but I still have the same issue.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Usually the question mark indicates the Font was not correct on receive side.  You should use encoding UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but using GET instead of POST worked, without defining any encoding options.

```
$message = "testing greek characters ΓΔΘΞΦΨΩ"
$senderId = "smsto1"
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $apikey")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

$response = Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.sms.to/sms/send?api_key=$apikey&to=+357$clientPhone&message=$message&sender_id=$senderId" -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
```